If I was 1-5 minutes late for ASR (or any other obligatory prayer) will make me a disbeliever?
I had 6 minutes before prayer, and I did wudu for the remaining time. I’m usually praying at home and I don’t have a Masjid anywhere nearby so I can hear it, but I do have the adhan on my Prayer Watch app, but I didn’t listen to it because by the time I finished my wudu, I had little time left and I rushed to pray. However I was late for the ASR prayer by  2 minutes, while NOT hearing the adhan, and I was wondering if my prayer counts, and do I become a kafir? (Disbeliever)
Also something to note: I suppose that I thought 6minutes or less was typically enough to do wudu but well of course I had my doubts so Allah knows the best if this counts as laziness or not

You say: "I’m usually praying at home" and I wonder if this is valid at all, as I heard (citation needed) that doing the obligatory prayers alone is only accepted in dire situations. Waiting for an answer based on Islam and not on hearsay as mine.

@GyroGearloose No, there's no such opinion that praying at home invalidates salat for both, men and women. All madhahib permit praying in the house, and the Hanafi madhab says that it is greater and more rewarding for the women to pray in the house than in the mosque.
